# Is it correct to write "Although not ... it was ..."?

Tags: sentence-construction

Example sentence:

> I closed my eyes, listening in Mary's voice. **Although not** balanced and
>   ladylike like my ex-girlfriend's, **it was** cheerful and melodious.

It this construction correct? Or the correct construction is **Although it wasn't**?

Comment: It's correct. But I am not a native. I am just saying this based my information. It's very common in formal writings. Where did you see this? I guess it's the contracted form of "although it was not"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concur, it is correct to use it like that. This is just a negative form of saying *although something something, I blah blah* where you just negate the information coming after *although*.

Example:

> **Although not** a native speaker, I'm still able to use this expression with utter excellence.